# How do I change the style of all markers in OpenLayers3?

Tags: openlayers

This is probably a newbie question, but am at my wits end.

I have a map that has several markers (see attached code).  What I am trying to do is alter ALL the markers depending on a map event (e.g., resizing marker for a zoom event). I am trying to do this without embedding the entire for loop creating markers within the event handler.  Any idea how I can change all markers together?

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/37sx9ewq/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<!-- OpenLayers CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.5.0/ol.min.css" type="text/css">

<!-- Map Modal starts -->
<div id="map" style="position:relative; max-width:100%; height:500px"></div>

<!-- OpenLayers JS -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ol3/3.5.0/ol.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- OpenLayers 3 Map Code -->
<script>
// Map center
var center_location = ol.proj.transform([-71,44], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

var olview = new ol.View({
   center: center_location,
   zoom: 8, 
})

// map tiles from OpenStreetMaps (OSM)
var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
   source: new ol.source.OSM()
});

var sourceFeatures = new ol.source.Vector();

var layerFeatures = new ol.layer.Vector({source: sourceFeatures});


var map = new ol.Map({
   target: 'map',
   view: olview,
   layers: [layer, layerFeatures],
   loadTilesWhileAnimating: true,
   loadTilesWhileInteracting: true,
});

map.on("moveend", function(e) {
   console.log(map.getView().getZoom());
});

var style1 = [
   new ol.style.Style({
       image: new ol.style.Icon({
           scale: .05,
           src: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e3/Green_Dot.svg",
      }),
    zIndex: 5,
}), 
];

// Lat/lon data
var places = [
    [-71,44],
    [-71.25,44],
    [-71.5,44],
    [-71.75,44],
    [-72,44]
    ];


// Iterate across lat/lon and create markers 
for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {

// markers
var feature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([places[i][0],places[i][1]], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
});

feature.setStyle(style1);

sourceFeatures.addFeature(feature);

} // end for loop

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the style via a style function on the layer.  You can add additional code to the function to test conditions and return different styles as necessary

```
var layerFeatures = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: sourceFeatures,
    style: function(feature, resolution) {
        return style1;
    }
});
```

Move the definition of `style1` above that code and remove this line

```
feature.setStyle(style1);
```

Comment: Will this automatically trigger when an event happens (eg, 'change-resolution')?

Comment: Resolution is one of the arguments of the style function. For a complex style definition see the [mapbox-streets-v6-style.js](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/examples/resources/mapbox-streets-v6-style.js) of the [Mapbox Vector Tiles Example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mapbox-vector-tiles.html)